# The USB drive is read only even write protection is off

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, usb-drive

I have made my Transcend USB 3.0 pendrive into bootable ARCH-LINUX key using dd command. After that it become read only and I was not able to use it. So I formatted as MBR with NTFS partition using Disk Utility in Ubuntu and there were no errors, but when I try to use it, it saying read-only and not allowing to copy anything.Here is the screenshot of the error.
[image: USB Error]

I had tried reformatting as GPT,the same error. I have tried EXT4 also.I have ran fsck command also, it says everything is clear. The following is the output of **dmesg | tail -n25**

```
[ 5399.004036] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:2c:41:38:db:7e:b7:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 5413.351497] type=1400 audit(1386569943.739:66): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=8956 comm="cupsd" pid=8956 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
[ 5438.323077] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:2c:41:38:c8:82:00:08:00 SRC=169.144.44.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=31744 PROTO=2 
[ 5463.333598] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:2c:41:38:db:7e:b9:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 5472.271930] usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 5479.546220] usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 5479.639030] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=8564, idProduct=1000
[ 5479.639039] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5479.639044] usb 2-1.5: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 5479.639047] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: JetFlash
[ 5479.639052] usb 2-1.5: SerialNumber: 1250498862
[ 5479.639699] scsi17 : usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
[ 5480.636704] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 8GB    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 5480.637548] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 5480.638034] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] 15433728 512-byte logical blocks: (7.90 GB/7.35 GiB)
[ 5480.638406] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 5480.638415] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 5480.638771] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: disabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 5480.650924]  sdb: sdb1
[ 5480.652992] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5480.798379] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[ 5486.400055] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:2c:41:38:db:7e:ae:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 5486.826155] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:2c:41:38:db:7e:af:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 5487.220538] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:2c:41:38:db:7e:ba:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 5514.209561] psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
```

Update: This is weird, I have formatted as FAT, I have checked the permissions, it is normal (-rw-r--r--). I have opened Terminal and used mkdir and a directory is created. I am able to create files also from cmdline, but whenever I try to access through nautilus , the error mentioned at the start is occuring. I have checked in my friend's laptop, there is no problem. Still can't understand the problem.

Comment: yes! you can recover your pendrive. Try formatting from a VM ware or virtualbox using backtrack or any other OS. if u couldnt format then try changing read only properties for owner and then come back to real window(non virtual), do format. it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the USB drive into FAT32 filesystem using GParted partition editor. After you do that, remove it from the PC, reboot the PC, and then re-insert the USB drive. Now it should work.

Try the below command to give read, write, execute permissions to your USB:

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/usbpartition-name
```

Comment: I am on my office laptop,and I don't have root access, I will try that in Personal Laptop. is there any difference , if we partition using Disk utility and Gparted ..? In Windows, I am unable to format it as it is saying USB device not recognized

Comment: just a piece of advice, if you can access windows, can you work your way around `diskpart.exe` in cmd.exe ?

Comment: In windows, it's not getting recognized, So I was unable to format in windows. I think this is random bug in Nautilus, after a reboot, everything is fine.

Comment: **Please don't recommend `0777` a.k.a. “please-hack-my-system-and-destroy-my-data” permissions for no apparent reason!** There's almost never a reason to do that because it can be avoided with more sensible modifications like changing (group) ownership. −1