# Fix my read-only pen drive to read-write

Tags: usb, filesystem

My 8 Gb pen drive has suddenly change to read-only. In fact 2 pen drives have changed to read-only.

I don't know about how the first pen drive changed into read-only, but with the second pen drive I tried to make a bootable pen drive using start-up disk creator. In the middle of writing suddenly it threw some error. After this I couldn't copy any files to the drive or delete any file from it any more.

How can I make a read-only drive writeable?

Comment: did you try to format through gparted?

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/a/388156/202806

Answer (score 1):

`find /dev/sdb -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;`

will make all the files read-writable by all { -rw-rw-rw- }

`find /dev/sdb -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

will make all files readable by all and writable by the owner { -rw-r--r-- }

-

assuming the flash drive is /dev/sdb (which is typical - but your mileage may vary).

Comment: You can find the `/dev/...` device name with `sudo fdisk -l`...

Comment: According to the duplicate question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable), `chmod` won't work because it is a write operation :/